# How to make an array of functions callable in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a class A which is basically a list of objects B.
I would like to be able to call a method in A which automatically
returns a list of the corresponding method in B:

A.method(x) = [B.method(x) for B in A]

The issue is that I need a dynamical behavior, so any method in B is
automatically "inherited" by A without having to hard code it.

I have tried using lambda functions and exec("""def ..."""),
but nothing seems to work. Here is an attempt:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self,Bs):
        self.listOfBs = Bs[:]

        if self.listOfBs:
            for method_name in dir(self.listOfBs[0]):
                if not callable(getattr(self.listOfBs[0],method_name)):
                    continue

            f = lambda x: [getattr(B,method_name)(x) for B in self.listOfBs]
            setattr(self,method_name,f)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self,name):

        self.name = name

    def getName(self,x):
        return self.name+x

#So if I define:
a = A([B('x'),B('y'),B('z')])

#I would like to have: a.getName('W') = ['xW','yW','zW']
#However I get the error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I think there should be an easy/elegant way of implementing the above behavior in python, but I couldn't find anything that works.

Comment: I think you have a typo here `a = A([B('x'),B)('y'),B('z')])` should be `a = A([B('x'), B('y'), B('z')])`

Comment: So you want your A class to have the same methods of B but when called, they should return an array of the equivalent calls of the wrapped B instances?

Comment: This questions inspired me to make a typed array metaclass. Imagine you have your `Item` class with properties, methods or slotted attributes. By doing `class ItemArray(metaclass=Array(Item): pass` it auto generates the code for the constructor of the form `__init__(self, *items, **kwargs):` and also autogenerates properties and methods for the `ItemArray` class that point to the contained items. This is, doing `array = ItemArray(Item(1), Item(2))`, `array.hello()` will call the hello method of both items and return a list with their results.

Comment: `array.a_property = [1, 2]` will set the property `a_property` of the underlying items to 1 and 2 respectively. And so on. Attributes of non-slotted underlying classes can not be exposed as they are not known at class build time. Attributes of slotted underlying classes, methods and properties are exposed (except if they are private/protected, this is, except if they start by _). Class variables are not exposed because it doesn't make sense. Would this kind of code be of interest? I can post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `__getattr__` to make method lookup dynamic

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, bs):
        self.bs = bs

    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        def call(*args, **kw):
            return [getattr(b, method_name)(*args, **kw) for b in bs]
        return call
```

Comment: This is one of the approaches that you could go for. You may want to check that the `method_name` string is a method of B.

Comment: @Adirio - I agree. can also add property support this way. I wanted to get AttributeError in case the method is missing - like a normal python object

Comment: Yeah, rising `AttributeError` when `B` doesnt have the called method should be the way to do the check.

Comment: Probably you want your `__getattr__` method to work for attributes, properties and methods, not only methods as in your answer. The other approach I was thinking of was with a MetaClass that reads B signature and creates the corresponding A class.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot. I had tried getattr before, but was missing some steps.
Just for the record, following Glazner's suggestion here is a working solution, which works both with attributes and methods:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self,Bs):
        self.listOfBs = Bs[:]

    def __getattr__(self, attr):

        if not all(hasattr(b,attr) for b in self.listOfBs):
            raise AttributeError("Attribute %s not found." %attr)


        val = getattr(self.listOfBs[0],attr)
        if not callable(val):
            return np.array([getattr(b,attr) for b in self.listOfBs])

        def call(*args, **kw):
            return [getattr(b, attr)(*args, **kw) for b in self.listOfBs]
        return call        

class B(object):
    def __init__(self,name):

        self.name = name

    def getName(self,x):
        return self.name+x


a = A([B('x'),B('y'),B('z')])
a.name #Returns ['x','y','z']
a.getName('W')  #Returns ['xW','yW','zW']
```